# meaning of divergence and its mathematical intuition

Tags: multivariable-calculus, differential-geometry

how does divergence which means sink or source equal to ∂Fx/∂x+∂Fy/∂y +∂Fz/∂z.I have been thinking it for a long time and i think "divergence tells us how fast the vector increases when we move apart from the vector source".
What has divergence which means sink or source has something to do with volume

Comment: Do you know that you can edit your questions?